# primefaces tree displays a list

Tags: jsf-2, tree, primefaces

I've copied the XHTML and the managed bean code from the primefaces multiple selection tree showcase page (for the basic tree showcase I've got the same result too).

Here is my `index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h:form id="form">

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" escape="false" />

        <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" selectionMode="multiple"
            selection="#{treeBean.selectedNodes}" id="treeMultiple">

            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>

        <p:commandButton value="Display Selected" update="messages"
            actionListener="#{treeBean.displaySelectedMultiple}" id="btnDisplay" />

    </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the bean:

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode root;

    private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;

    public TreeBean() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);
        TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);

        TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);
        TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);
        TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);

        TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public TreeNode[] getSelectedNodes() {
        return selectedNodes;
    }

    public void setSelectedNodes(TreeNode[] selectedNodes) {
        this.selectedNodes = selectedNodes;
    }

    public void displaySelectedMultiple(ActionEvent event) {
             if(selectedNodes != null && selectedNodes.length > 0) {
                 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for(TreeNode node : selectedNodes) {
                builder.append(node.getData().toString());
                builder.append("<br />");
            }


  FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected",builder.toString());

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
    }
}
```

and all I got was something like a simple list:

> • Node 0
>   • Node 1
>   • Node 2

it looks like Ajax, CSS or/and JavaScript code is missing... but it's not mentioned to add that in the showcase.
Thanks for the help!

tomcat 7
eclipse juno
webapp configuration: 
jsf 2.1
dynamic webapp 3.0
java 6

Comment: Please format your codes. It's horrible to read.

Comment: @RinaldoPJr it s done !! it s a newbie mistake , i m sorry ! :)

Comment: @user1705922 are you not able to expand the nodes ?? i tried your code and it works perfectly fine .. can you be clear what you are not able to achieve :)

Comment: yes i cant expand the nodes; i m expecting also that node's background color changes when the mouse is over it but for me nothing happen and i cant even select them..i dont also have arrows at node lefts like in the showcase. by the way in my pom i ve the 3.3 primefaces jar and jsf 2.1.11 jars version.

Comment: it s fixed ! well, in my firefox browser,i opened the web console and found a js error (primefaces is not defined) and in the source code shown in the browser which is generated by jsf, within the primefaces growl tag i found this  message {id:'form:messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:false,msgs:[{summary:"Une ou plusieurs ressources partagent la cible «head», mais aucun composant «head» n\u2019a été défini dans la vue.".. and the solution was to use <h:head></h:head> instead of <head></head> in the xhtml page where the tree's form is.